# Content not added to computed field using Azure Search

Tags: content-search, azure-search

There is a custom code which triggers on rebuilding indexes. The method will extract all content from each page rendering's datasources and store in the content field.

When I debug, I see that the datasource content is correctly extracted. However, in the search method, the same content is not found.

```
//This function is triggered when rebuilding indexes is performed in CMS
public class SubcontentField : IComputedIndexField
{    
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
            {
                var sitecoreIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

                if (sitecoreIndexable == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                //it is assumed that the home item is the same in master & web databases
                Item homeItem = GetHomeItem(SiteName, MasterDatabaseName);
                List<string> contentToAdd = new List<string>();

                //add values (of only the page items that are under home) to the computed field.
                if (homeItem != null && (sitecoreIndexable.Item.ID == homeItem.ID || sitecoreIndexable.Item.Paths.IsDescendantOf(homeItem)))
                {
                    // find renderings with datasources set
                    IEnumerable<Item> customDataSources = ExtractRenderingDataSourceItems(sitecoreIndexable.Item);
                    IEnumerable<Item> relatedItems = customDataSources.SelectMany(GetRelatedItems);

                    // extract text from data sources
                    contentToAdd = customDataSources.SelectMany(GetItemContent).ToList();
                    contentToAdd.AddRange(relatedItems.SelectMany(GetItemContent));

                    if (contentToAdd.Count == 0) return null;
                }

                return string.Join("|", contentToAdd);
            }
}
```

**Search Method:**

```
private void GetSearchResults(string keywords)
{
  using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(index).CreateSearchContext())
  {
                IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                    .Where(x => x.Content.Contains(keywords) && x.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
   if (query != null && query.Count() > 0)
   {

   }
 }
}
```

I have checked for a particular keyword when rebuilding the web_index and when searched for the same, the `query` is always null.

We are using `Azure Search`.

Comment: Just noting that Azure Search has limitations:  Documentation: "Substring searches that are limited to a single term, for instance, predicates, .StartsWith(), .EndsWith() and .Contains(), will match parts of terms, and will match terms that are located in any part of the field value. When multiple terms are passed, each term is searched separately, (this can provide more results than expected)."


Also, are you trying this on Sitecore 8 or 9?   Sitecore 9 appends a postfix to the field name depending on type.

Comment: hey, did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

This first thing I'd do here is go to your Solr instance and query it directly to check if the content is there or not. e.g:

> https://solr:8983/solr/web_index/select?q=subcontent:test

If it isn't then check your configuration for your computed field is correct. e.g:

```
<defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                        <field fieldName="subcontent" storageType="YES" returnType="text">YourNameSpace.SubContentField</field>
                </fields>
</defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
```

Comment: I'm using azure search and no access to portal. Any other way. What abt the code. Is there something wrong with it

Comment: It looks like you can still query it directly: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-explorer

Comment: Do not have access to the portal.

Comment: Ok if this really isn't possible, looking at your Search query it looks ok. Try also adding Or predicates for Lowercase and Titlecase versions of the query to check it's not an casing issue.

Comment: I checked the content field in a for loop too. It doesnt have the keyword at all.

Comment: the field name i have used in the patch config is "_content". do you think that is the issue

Comment: I’m assuming the content field is a custom field? If so then I’d say that could be your issue as the item name field for example is called: _name in Sitecore so that is what is passed to query the name field but your custom field is unlikely to be prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72764/discussion-between-qwerty-and-adam-seabridge).